# Not able to embed link in add/remove program

Tags: nsis

I created an window application for which I need to create setup.For creating setup i am using NSIS. I had written script to create setup file I need to link this setup file to  Add/remove program. For add link to add/remove program I am using following code:

```
   WriteRegStr HKCU "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\app" "DisplayName" "Name"
   WriteRegStr HKCU "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\app" "AppName" '"$INSTDIR\UninstallApp.exe"'
```

This code successfully add the details in registry      **Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\app**
but not able to add link to add/remove.

Comment: app is not a good key name, use a guid or something more specific...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try HKLM with ADMIN rights? i.e. Launch your installer with administrative privileges.

Code snipped should look like this

```
!include "MUI2.nsh"

!define PRODUCT_NAME             "MyProduct"
!define PRODUCT_UNINST_REGKEY    "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}"
!define PRODUCT_DEF_LOC          "$PROGRAMFILES\${PRODUCT_NAME}"
!define PRODUCT_UNINSTALLER      "MyUninstaller.exe"

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

Name         "${PRODUCT_NAME} Test"
OutFile      "${PRODUCT_NAME}_Setup.exe"
InstallDir   "${PRODUCT_DEF_LOC}"


Section "Core section" SecCore

    SetOutPath $INSTDIR

    WriteRegExpandStr HKLM "${PRODUCT_UNINST_REGKEY}" "UninstallString" "$INSTDIR\${PRODUCT_UNINSTALLER}"
    WriteRegStr       HKLM "${PRODUCT_UNINST_REGKEY}" "DisplayName"     "Name"

    WriteUninstaller  "$INSTDIR\${PRODUCT_UNINSTALLER}"

SectionEnd



Section "Uninstall"
    Delete "$INSTDIR\${PRODUCT_UNINSTALLER}"
    RMDir  $INSTDIR
    DeleteRegKey HKLM "${PRODUCT_UNINST_REGKEY}"
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.I tried the code you suggested but didn't work.

Comment: I have changed my initial comment to a completely working example. Tested and working on my system (win7 64 bit). Run with admin rights.

Comment: Thanks for this informative post.Now I am having another issue that when I am uninstalling the app with add/remove feature the registry content is not getting delete.

Comment: @Anders Ok fine can you elaborate the reason for not using writeRegExpandStr.

Comment: Because $InstDir is not going to start with %ProgramFiles% or anything useful so nothing good can come from using REG_EXPAND_SZ and if the user installed it somewhere silly like c:\foo\%OS%\bar then %OS% will get expanded and ARP cannot find your uninstall.exe

Answer (score 0):

According to [the official documentation](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Add_uninstall_information_to_Add/Remove_Programs), the hive HKCU is only supported for NT4/2000/XP for the current user.

Try to use the HKLM instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are two required uninstall string entries and they are `DisplayName` and `UninstallString`.

The other entries like `URLInfoAbout` are optional but the two required entries must be present to show the item in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I updated my code as per your suggestion but still its not working.